# Is there any handy command line tool to manage Cron jobs?

Tags: bash, unix, solaris, cron

Would someone suggest any handy command line (NOT web) tool or script which adds, enables and disables Cron jobs? I am looking, for example, for the following (or similar) behavior:

```
sh manageCron.sh -idJob 'job1' -addJob '* * * * * <do some job>'
sh manageCron.sh -dissableJob 'job1'
```

`crontab -e` command is good for manual editing of crontab file, but I need to automate.

Comment: interesting idea, but to implement safely will be a non-trivial project. If your crontabs are so big or complex that you need managment tools, don't forget to start using source-code-control on your crontabs. `crontab -l > crontab.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M)` at the bare minimum. Good luck.

Comment: Also, note the low number of users for most of your tags (when you rollover your mouse on them). tag=ksh or tag=bash will increase the number of users likely to look at your question. (I have never seen a script that does what you ask). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter: Don't add a "ksh" tag when the question has nothing to do with ksh.

Comment: @KeithThompson : the project could be written as a ksh script, couldn't it?

Comment: @shellter: Yes -- or bash, or tcsh, or Perl, or Cobol.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing preventing you from using -e in an automated way.  As a trivial example, you can do a search and replace in your crontab (if your sed supports -i) with:

```
$ VISUAL='sed -i s/foo/bar/g' crontab -e
```

So write a program that modifies the file in the way you want and set VISUAL to that program.